# Qiskit Variational Quantum Regressor - Qiskit VQR

Tags: quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, variational-quantum-algorithms, qiskit

I am new to quantum machine learning and I am trying to build a VQR with Qiskit. The input and target data to my model both have shape (32,4), where 32 is the number of samples and 4 is the number of features per sample (so I have 32 vectors with 4 features each). I want to use ZZFeatureMap as my feature map but i have problems setting the input and target data dimensions correctly so that the ZZFeatureMap processes correctly the input and prepares the desired state. Here's my code which i based on the code from [qiskit's vqr example](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.html). Here is my code:

```
def callback_graph(weights, obj_func_eval):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    objective_func_vals.append(obj_func_eval)
    plt.title("Objective function value against iteration")
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel("Objective function value")
    plt.plot(range(len(objective_func_vals)), objective_func_vals)
   #plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()

algorithm_globals.random_seed = 42

num_features= 4
num_samples = 32

xdef = np.array([i for i in range(1,num_features*num_samples+1)]) # Features are dict indices in my case (no 0 idx desired)
xdef = xdef/np.linalg.norm(xdef)
xdef = xdef.reshape(num_samples, num_features)

ydef = np.array([i**2 for i in range(1,num_features*num_samples+1)]) # As if the function f in y=f(x) is f(x) = x**2
ydef = ydef/np.linalg.norm(ydef)
ydef = ydef.reshape(num_samples, num_features)

xpred = np.array([i for i in range(100,228)]) # Considering features the model has never seen
xpred = xpred/np.linalg.norm(xpred)
xpred = xpred.reshape(num_samples,num_features)

num_qubits = int(np.log2(num_samples*num_features))
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=num_qubits, reps=1)
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(num_qubits=num_qubits, entanglement='full')

vqr = VQR(feature_map=feature_map,
          ansatz = ansatz,
    optimizer=COBYLA(maxiter=50),
    callback=callback_graph,
)

# create empty array for callback to store evaluations of the objective function
objective_func_vals = []
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20, 6)

# fit regressor
vqr.fit(xdef, ydef)

# return to default figsize
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20, 4)

# score result
print(vqr.score(xdef, ydef))

# plot target function
plt.plot(list(xdef), list(ydef), "r--")
plt.show()

# plot fitted line
y_ = vqr.predict(xpred)

plt.plot(list(xpred), list(y_), "g-")
plt.show()
```

but i get get this error:

```
QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs: 7, but got: 4.'
```

When i try

```
num_qubits = 4
```

i get this error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 128 into shape (32,1)
```

Im confused as to what shape does the VQR class object expects for xdef and ydef... Anyone has an idea how should i reshape my input data so that the amplitude encoding gets done properly by the ZZFeatureMap ?